# Moving object accelerates when it shouldn´t

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Sorry if the title is vague.
The idea of this code is to create objects on a canvas and make it move left to right and viceversa, and when it hits a border of the screen it moves 50 pixels down and proceeds to move left or right depending on which side of the screen it is.

It works, but the objects starts to accelerate as it goes down. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def enemigos():
    global Enemigos
    
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    if n == 1:
        
        alien1 = CanvasJuego.create_image(0,0, anchor = NW, image = Enemigos[0], tags= ('alien1'))
        def movalien1(direc):
            CoordsAlien1 = CanvasJuego.coords(alien1)
            
            if CoordsAlien1[0] <= 923 and direc==1:
                CanvasJuego.move(alien1,5,0)
                root.after(20,lambda: movalien1(1))
            if CoordsAlien1[0]>=923 and direc==1:
                CanvasJuego.move(alien1,0,50)
                root.after(20,lambda:movalien1(0))
            if CoordsAlien1[0]>=0 and direc==0:
                CanvasJuego.move(alien1,-5, 0)
                root.after(20,lambda:movalien1(0))
            if CoordsAlien1[0]<=0 and direc==0:
                CanvasJuego.move(alien1,0,50)
                root.after(20,lambda:movalien1(1))
            
        root.after(20,lambda: movalien1(1))
    
def tiempoenemigos(tiempo):
    root.after(tiempo,enemigos)
    root.after(tiempo, lambda: tiempoenemigos(tiempo))
```

Why is it accelerating? Any other sugestions are welccome.

Comment: You have scheduled more than once to execute `enemigos()` periodically because `tiempoenemigos()` is executed periodically.  Try removing `root.after(...)` inside `enemigos()`.

Comment: Every time your alien's x-coordinate is exactly equal to 0 (or to 923), there is a possibility for *two* of your `if` conditions to be true during the same call - because you are comparing to that number with both `<=` and `>=`.  Every time this happens, you call `.after()` twice, so the position starts being updated twice as often.  Remove the `=`  from one of the comparisons in each pair.

Comment: Daym that sounds cool

Comment: @jasonharper This solved the problem, thank you!